# geth web3 api with web3 version 1?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, geth-debugging

Due to security concerns with rpc, I'd like to tunnel into my geth instance and run ipc commands. However, all the scripts I've written use version 1 beta of web3, which geth does not yet support.

I'm wondering if anyone is aware of an upcoming geth release that will roll out with web3 v1, or if geth now allows you to set the web3 api version manually (doubtful on the latter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the web3 v1 docs, ipc can now be set just like any websocket or http provider. This definitely gets around the issue of hooking the v1 beta release into geth.

`var web3 = new Web3('/users/myuser/.ethereum/geth.ipc', net);` *(in linux)*

A ssh tunnel is required to make the connection to a remote node, but this falls outside the scope of discussion. If anyone needs help with tunnelling from a node.js instance let me know and I'll write out an implementation guide.